# Problems using fgets

Tags: c, fgets, fifo

I have to deal with an assignment and I have to use a FIFO file for IPC.

The main problem is that I´m stuck on the `fget` part. I´ve open the file already, but when I try to read the data stored on it, the program just stop working. It doesn´t really hungs, the program just doesn´t do anything.

I´m pretty sure that is a problem with the `fgets` syscall, because I´ve been debugging and the problem shows just only when I include the `fgets()` line on the code.

// ESCRITURA DENTRO DEL ARCHIVO FIFO QUE ABRIRA EJ2.
        //Creamos los fifos, comprobando que no existen

```
    mknod("fichero1", S_IFIFO|0777,0);
    fp= fopen("fichero1", "w+"); //Abrimos el archivo fifo
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("Fallo al abrir el archivo, no se encuentra");
        exit(0);
    }
    fputs(msgrec, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("El proceso P2 ha creado el archivo fichero1 y ha esctito el mensaje ");

    fp = fopen("fichero1", "w+");


    if (fgets(msgre, sizeof(msgrec), fp) == NULL){
        printf("Fallo al leer el archivo");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("\n I´m here"); // DEBUGING LINE

    //Here is how he code continues.
    /*

    printf(" Lo que esta en el earchivo que es: %s \n", msgre);
    printf("%s \n", msgrec);





    execv("Ej2", 0); //Ejecucion del archivo Ej2
    */

}
```

Comment: typo ? `msgre` -> `msgrec`

Answer (score 2):

Change your second fopen call from a write-append mode `fp = fopen("fichero1", "w+");` to

```
fp = fopen("fichero1", "r"); /* read mode */
```

I, also notice this -

```
if (fgets(msgrec, sizeof(msgrec), fp) == NULL){ // msgrec, not msgre.
```

Comment: Hi. I´ve tried that with same result. I don´t know what is happening, I´ve gone through several docs about this, and I´m doing the right things (obviously not).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will post all the code. I deliberate change the msgre thing. The problem deals with the reading from a fifo file. I´ve tried changing frets to write (with all the necessary file id changes) and it doesn't work. I can open the file, close the file and also write into the file (I think), but by the time I try to read the FIFO content it just don't do anything. Thanks a lot for your help. Really Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're on a Unix/Linux system. You could replace the library calls `fopen`, `fputs`, `fgets` with the corresponding raw system calls `open`, `write`, `read` and see what happens. The system calls don't do any user-space buffering, so it might be easier to debug.

The main trick with FIFOs is that the `open` syscall blocks until the other end of the FIFO is opened as well.

Comment: I think that the problem deals with that "closing" issue. but I don't find the mistake. I´ve review all the variables staff and the program compiles well. I think that maybe the FIFO is not open to read or something.

Comment: At last I´ve found the problem. I closed the fifo file before opening it on the other side. I was exactly what you said. Thanks a lot. So sad I can't vote. Thanks a lot to everybody